# self-reference not allowed in Security Group definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create an sg with Terraform.

I want all instances of a particular SG to have all communication allowed among them, so I am adding the SG itself to the ingress rules as follows:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "rancher-server-sg" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.rancher-vpc.id}"
  name = "rancher-server-sg"
  description = "security group for rancher server"

  ingress {
      from_port = 0
      to_port = 0
      protocol = -1
      security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.rancher-server-sg.id}"]              
  }
```

However when running `terraform plan`, I get:

However, in the AWS console, I am allowed to add an SG name in the  inbound rules and I see that I can add the group itself (i.e. self-referenced).

Why is that?

I have also tried this without success:

```
security_groups = ["${self.id}"]
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Citing [the manual](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html):

> self - (Optional) If true, the security group itself will be added as
>   a source to this ingress rule.

```
  ingress {
      from_port = 0
      to_port = 0
      protocol = -1
      self = true
  }
```

Comment: Does this mean you do not provide the `cidr_blocks` value for the egress attribute?

Comment: Updated link to [the manual](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group)